# Is there anyway to group my data per year that will summarize it and make it 1?

Tags: javascript, c#, highcharts

in my code im trying to display all the enrolled students per year and i want to summarize them all in 1 column per year.
is there anyway to add filter or most likely in the code itselft to combine all the data per year?

```
    var strCampus = "ORT";

            $(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://localhost:37590/Get_OGSData/" + strCampus, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
        },
         rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },
      title: {
        text: 'On Going Students per Year'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Click each column to see details'
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: data.map(function(x) {
          return x.YEAR;
        })
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'On Going Students'
        }
        },


        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          borderWidth: 0,
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            //format: '{point.y:.1f}'
          }
        }
      },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: false,
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:2f}</b> of total<br/>'
      },
      series: [{
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: data.map(function(x) {
          return x.OGS * 1;
        })
      }]
    });
  });
});
```

i want to combine all the data per year in 1 column

Comment: Check the array's reduce here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Do you want to do it in C# or JS?

Comment: in JS to be display in Highcharts

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dataGrouping` with options below:

```
    dataGrouping: {
        approximation: 'sum',
        forced: true,
        units: [
            ['year', [1]]
        ]
    }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/me3Lzur6/

API reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.dataGrouping